# (jQuery) addClass to whole row

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add class to whole `row` where text is "null" or rating is less or equal to 5.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("thead tr td:nth-child(3)").each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == 'null')
          $(this).text('No rating found').addClass("table-danger");
          else if ( $(this).text() <= '5' ) {       
          //if value is smaller or equal to 5 don't works
               $(this).text().addClass("table-danger");
          }
     });
});
```

> **FiddleJS**: https://jsfiddle.net/e0svzss9/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/e0svzss9/7/)

You can use parent('tr') to work with your code.

```
  $(this).text('No rating found').parent('tr').addClass("table-danger");
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong

```
 $(this).text().addClass("table-danger");
```

It should be

```
 $(this).addClass("table-danger");
```

Edit :

Use Parents  tag to navigate to the tr

i.e

```
$(this).parents('tr')
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9knfcdp8/)

Comment: Yes this was wrong, but it still don't add class to whole row to tr element.

Comment: use parents to get the tr.
i.e $(this).parents('tr')

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$(this).text().addClass("table-danger");
```

add

```
$(this).parents('tr').addClass("table-danger");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parent()

```
$(this).text('No rating found').parent().addClass("table-danger");
```